# C4566: символ, представленный универсальным именем символа "\u0420", невозможно представить в текущей кодовой странице (1252)

Tags: c++, visual-studio, кодировка, project, charset

Установил недвано Win10 полностью на английском языке, поставил Visual Studio 2017. При сборке любого проекта с русским текстов вылезают предупреждения C4566 и текст не работает корректно.
Приведу пример:

```
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    std::cout << "Русский текст";
}
```

Лог компиляции:

```
1>------ Сборка начата: проект: Project1, Конфигурация: Debug Win32 ------
1>Source.cpp
1>c:\users\asdas\desktop\repository\project1\project1\source.cpp(4): warning C4566: символ, представленный универсальным именем символа "\u0420", невозможно представить в текущей кодовой странице (1252)
1>c:\users\asdas\desktop\repository\project1\project1\source.cpp(4): warning C4566: символ, представленный универсальным именем символа "\u0443", невозможно представить в текущей кодовой странице (1252)
1>c:\users\asdas\desktop\repository\project1\project1\source.cpp(4): warning C4566: символ, представленный универсальным именем символа "\u0441", невозможно представить в текущей кодовой странице (1252)
1>c:\users\asdas\desktop\repository\project1\project1\source.cpp(4): warning C4566: символ, представленный универсальным именем символа "\u043A", невозможно представить в текущей кодовой странице (1252)
1>c:\users\asdas\desktop\repository\project1\project1\source.cpp(4): warning C4566: символ, представленный универсальным именем символа "\u0438", невозможно представить в текущей кодовой странице (1252)
1>c:\users\asdas\desktop\repository\project1\project1\source.cpp(4): warning C4566: символ, представленный универсальным именем символа "\u0439", невозможно представить в текущей кодовой странице (1252)
1>c:\users\asdas\desktop\repository\project1\project1\source.cpp(4): warning C4566: символ, представленный универсальным именем символа "\u0442", невозможно представить в текущей кодовой странице (1252)
1>c:\users\asdas\desktop\repository\project1\project1\source.cpp(4): warning C4566: символ, представленный универсальным именем символа "\u0435", невозможно представить в текущей кодовой странице (1252)
1>Project1.vcxproj -> C:\Users\asdas\Desktop\repository\Project1\Debug\Project1.exe
1>Сборка проекта "Project1.vcxproj" завершена.
========== Сборка: успешно: 1, с ошибками: 0, без изменений: 0, пропущено: 0 ==========
```

Можно ли как то это исправить, не изменяя каждый проект при создании? Изменить что то в настройках vs, изменить значение в реестре какое?

Comment: А это все оттого, что Вы установили текущей "не юникод"-кодировкой cp1252, а кириллица есть только в cp1251. Лечится настройками системы, где про локализацию. И да, это все последствия `"Установил недвано Win10 полностью на английском языке"`.

Comment: @Vladimir, понимаю, что это все последствия установки win10 eng))) Спасибо за ответ, попробую настроить.

Comment: Заканчивался 2019 год. В винде всё ещё по умолчанию однобайтная кодировка…

Comment: @AlexeyTen, а как ещё ты хочешь упихать символы в однобайтовый char?

Comment: Человечество придумало utf8 и разницу между байтами и символами

Comment: @AlexeyTen, а еще это "человечество" придумало utf7/utf16/utf32, LE/BE, с BOM/без BOM и идите развлекайтесь со всем этим зоопарком и пытайтесь делать программу так, чтобы везде работала. Не думаете, что это немного не удобно?

Comment: А развлекаться с cp1251/1252/866/417 это комильфо конечно. Да фиг бы с ним с зоопарком. Я больше о том что *кодировка по умолчанию* в винде всё ещё не какая-нибудь многобайтная.

Comment: А вообще это заморочки VS. gcc на линуксе по барабану кодировки ибо char* это набор байт и нечего в них буквы выискивать.

Comment: @AlexeyTen, не в защиту выньдовса, но ради справедливости - в винде давно уже кодировка Unicode (она же UTF16LE на персоналках, если не ошибаюсь). А в вопросе речь была про кодировку для старых однобайтовых приложений (и это касается сейчас, в основном, только консольных программ).

Answer (score 2):

Решил вопрос.
Чинится следующим образом:
Control Panel -> Region -> Administrative -> Language for non-Unicode programs -> Change system locale